# RubyOnRails - option_groups_from_collection_for_select and translation of content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouped-collection-select

I have a collection, I am showing to the user.
But I need to I18n.translate the :key into a readable text from my de.yml.

```
competences:
  key:
    compkey001: "Werbung / 360"
    compkey001subkey002: "Klassische Werbung / ATL"
    compkey002: "Strategie"

f.input :competence_id, label: "Kompetenz", :as => :select,
:collection => option_groups_from_collection_for_select(
@competence_kategories, :competence_unterkats, t(:key, 
scope: 'basic_data.competences'), :id, t(:key, 
scope: 'basic_data.competences'))
```

This is not working.
It is giving me an error, something like: t() is not a method.

The below line is working, but showing the keys that are not usable by the user:

```
f.input :competence_id, label: "Kompetenz", :as => :select, 
:collection => option_groups_from_collection_for_select( 
@competence_kategories, :competence_unterkats, :key, :id, :key)
```

Displayed will be:

```
(bold)compkey001
  compkey001subkey001
(bold)compkey002
... etc.
```

How can I get the translations being displayed in a grouped manner?

Thanks for help!

Comment: what error do you get `I18n.t` using it?

Comment: CompetenceUnterkat Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `competences`.* FROM `competences` WHERE `competences`.`type` IN ('CompetenceU
nterkat') AND `competences`.`competence_kategorie_key` = 'compkey001'
  Rendered case_competences/_form.html.haml (31.2ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/smart_listing-1.1.2/app/views/smart_listing/item/_new.js.erb (31.2ms)
  Rendered case_competences/new.js.erb (62.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 234ms (ActiveRecord: 62.4ms)

Comment: I think it should be `t(:compkey001, scope: 'basic_data.competences.key') ` instead.

Comment: Sorry, that is not working. "compkey001" is a key in the de.yml, and no attribute of any model. t(... expects an attribute at that place. And that :compkey001 is a fixed value in my situation.

Comment: `t("basic_data.competences.key.#{key}")` try this then.

Comment: That is bringing out this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method ``key' for #<#<Class:0x741e208>:0xa3c5ab0>):`

Comment: Changing to:

`= f.input :competence_id, label: "Kompetenz", :as => :select, :collection => option_groups_from_collection_for_select( @competence_kategories, :competence_unterkats, (t("basic_data.competences.key.#{:key}")), :id, :key)`
shows this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: de.basic_da
ta.competences.key.key">Key</span>' for #<CompetenceKategorie:0x9a31208>):'

And if I delete the 2nd .key the error is as written in my very first comment-response.

Comment: The third param of option_groups_from_collection_for_select  should be an attribute or method of competence_kategories object (which returns string) and the fifth parameter should be an attribute or method of competence_unterkats object (which returns string). Then this would work

Comment: Thanks for your extensive help Vamsi.
I understand that.
But I do not have any attribute to hold that text. I have only the key. And that is directing to my de.yml for german (or en.yml if english).
And I really do not know how to get the text from the de.yml file included instead of the key attribute of my model.
May be I need to create a new Hash containing all needed values in the controller or model.
I was looking for an easy way to get these translations displayed, but there seems not to be a solution or do I need to poste more details?

Comment: I think you can try writing methods in each model. In competence_kategories model you can write `def list_categories (1..2).each do |i| [t("basic_data.competences.key.compkey00#{i}")] end end` and you can create a similar method to get sub category values alone in competence_unterkats model `def sub_categories(category) (1..2).each do |i| [t("basic_data.competences.key.#{category}.subkey00#{i}")] end end`

Comment: Okay. But I do have more than two entries. I now added this to my CompetenceKategorie model

`def list_competencekategories 
   CompetenceKategorie.each do |cki|
    [t(ck.key, scope: 'basic_data.competences')]
  end 
end `

and this to my CompetenceUnterkat model

`def list_competenceunterkat
   CompetenceUnterkat.each do |cu|
      [t(cu.key, scope: 'basic_data.competences')]
   end 
end `

How can I address these in the _form.html?

Comment: Finally I made it !!!
The last statement from Vamsi helped me.
I have added a virtual field to my model with:
 ` def name_of_kategorie
    I18n.t(key, scope: 'basic_data.competences.key')
  end '
That (also added on the other model for competence_unterkat) generated a new field in my model that I now am able to use in my view for the option_group:
'option_groups_from_collection_for_select( @competence_kategories, :competence_unterkats, :name_of_kategorie, :id, :name_of_unterkat)'
Thanks a lot for helping me here.

Comment: Your comment @Cokiehh should be marked as valid answer, this is exactly what I was looking for and could probably help more people